# MS Office no longer works as BLOB

Tags: mysql, ms-office, blob

Hi does anyone know why MS Office such as doc, docx and xls can no longer be viewed when retrieved from a mysql db when stored as Blob?
The doc and docx used to download and open without any problem, but now it no longer recognises the file format.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to ditto your problem. Images and plain text files upload/download from mysql blob field. Doc and docx files seemed to be corrupted. I've read somewhere of a rumor of mysql truncating the last 4 bits but I can't verify that.

Comment: A rumour? "I can't verify that". 1 or 0 or maybe -1 if using access. Truncation could be a cause but truncation would result in multiple errors across all file formats.

Answer (score 1):

I have used xvi32 (a hex editor) to compare local originals of files with versions dowloaded from BLOB/LONGBLOB fields. It seems that extra bytes, which I think represent a CRLF are appended, as far as I can work out by Windows when the file is written.  This doesn't seem to be a problem for some graphic formats which are to some extent fault-tolerant, but the office XML format files are corrupted by this extra data.

I have tried using ob_clean() and ob_flush() [that is, in php] before printing/echoing the file contents, but still corrupted as far as Office is concerned.

I know this is an old thread but I would appreciate any solutions anyone might have found since it was last updated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a short txt file instead of .doc and see if the contents are different than what you expected?

Comment: The .doc and .docx worked originally. PDF works, but nothing Office downloads correctly in binary when retrieved from the database, whether this is a change in mysql, php or MS, I am without a path to follow.
Thankyou for your time EsbenP.